# Clean up concatenated XML files

Tags: sed, awk, xml

I'm trying to fix my [Delicious export script](https://github.com/l0b0/export/blob/master/Delicious.sh) to work with the new "[trick](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2011/10/29/good-bye-delicious/)" of only serving 1000 bookmarks at a time. The script concatenates results (XML) from multiple calls in a single file, and now I have to get rid of the header and footer text from the resulting file. Example:

```
<?xml ...
<posts ...
  <post ...
  ...          # 998 other posts
  <post ...
</posts>     # Line 1003
# The above lines are repeated N times before the final line:
</posts>
```

In other words, I want to remove any lines not starting with `<post` between (excluding) the third and the last line, and each chunk of XML is 1003 lines exactly, except for possibly the last one.

I'm guessing `sed` or `awk` should be perfect for this.

Comment: So do you need lines only with `<posts` or `<posts` and `<post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

```
sed -i -e '3,${/^</d}' file
```

In other words, between lines 3 and the last line, remove any line which starts with a `<`. Sorry the indentation didn't show up in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the consistant format of the data, head and tail are your friends. This should even work for the last shorter file.

```
cat file | tail -n +3 | head -n -1 > trimmed_file
```

The tail -n +3 takes everything from the 3rd line down to the end of the file, and head -n -1 takes everything except the last line of the file.

Once you have a set of trimmed files, cat them together with an appropriate header and footer section for the whole file.

UPDATE: to avoid creating lots of extra files, just wrap it in a for loop:

```
for i in *
do
    cat $i | tail -n +3 | head -n -1 >> newfile
done
```

Get a template for the header by running one of the files through head to extract the first 3 lines, then run the for loop above. Then do a similar thing with tail to get the last line of one of the files and append it to newfile. I imagine you'll need to update the header and footer information.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid any temporary files, which is why I asked how to do it inline.

Comment: for i in *; do cat $i | tail -n +3 | head -n -1 >> newfile; done

Comment: Won't this pass strings at each whitespace??

Comment: Jaypal - I apologise, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Hi @dr-jan, what I mean't was if the line contains a white space string eg. `this post`, then for loop, instead of using the whole line will pass `this` first and then `post`.

Comment: @Jaypal - no because the for loop is dealing with files, not lines within files - it should be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit clunky. Why not process the data as it comes in?

```
bookmarks_count=$chunk_size
total_bookmarks_count=0
{
  while [ $bookmarks_count -eq $chunk_size ]; do
    chunk=$(wget … -O - "$EXPORT_URL?start=$total_bookmarks_count")
    bookmarks_count=$(printf %s "$chunk" | grep -c "$bookmark_prefix")
    total_bookmarks_count=$((total_bookmarks_count + bookmarks_count))
    printf %s "$chunk" |
    sed -e 's#><#>\n<#g' -e "$EXPORT_COMPATIBILITY" -e "$EXPORT_COMPATIBILITY"
  done
  echo '<\/posts>'
} >"$EXPORT_PATH"
```

You can even avoid storing each chunk in memory, though it's a bit trickier. Here's a method that only works in ksh and zsh; in other shells, the right-hand side of the pipeline runs in a subshell so the value of `total_bookmarks_count` is not updated.

```
{
  total_bookmarks_count=0
  while
      wget … -O - "$EXPORT_URL?start=$bookmarks_count" |
      sed -e … |
      tee /dev/fd/3 |
      this_chunk_size=$(grep -c "$bookmark_prefix")
      [[ $this_chunk_size = $chunk_size ]]
  do
    ((total_bookmarks_count += chunk_size))
  done
  echo '<\/posts>' >&3
} 3>"$EXPORT_PATH"
```

Here's a way to make this method work in other shells, where the only information you can get out of a pipeline is its return status.

```
: >"$EXPORT_PATH"
total_bookmarks_count=0
while
    wget … -O - "$EXPORT_URL?start=$bookmarks_count" |
    sed -e … |
    tee -a "$EXPORT_PATH" |
    [ $(grep -c "$bookmark_prefix") = $chunk_size ]
do
  total_bookmarks_count=$((total_bookmarks_count + chunk_size))
done
echo '<\/posts>' >> "$EXPORT_PATH"
```